# Where on my network is my HP Laser Jet Pro?

Tags: networking, printer

I have a new HP LaserJet Pro, which I plugged in to my wired network (through a switch, in case that matters).  I can print to it from a Windows 10 machine plugged in to the same wired network and the same switch.

Looking in the DHCP leases on my pfsense router, I don't see an entry for the printer, and in the Windows 10 properties for the printer it shows its location in the following format:

http://[xxdd::ddd:xxxx:xxdd:xxdd%dd]:dddd/

(x represents a hex digit; d represents a numeric digit, the rest are literal.)

What's going on?  That doesn't look to me like an IPV6 address, but is it?

Update:  Ok, that is an IPv6 address and there is a separate status page on my router with IPv6 leases and there it does show this address associated with this printer's mac address.  Apparently it just configured itself by default to communicate via IPv6.

Comment: Go to the Laser Jet Control Panel on the Printer, Network Settings, and give it a static IP on your network (and set Mask and Gateway).  Now restart the printer and restart your computer.You should now see the printer

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that suggestion, but I'd like to understand what is going on in the default configuration.

Comment: You would need to check the DHCP settings of your workstation setup, because (assuming the printer is fine) it will get an address from most DHCP servers.

Comment: Start by printing a configuration page on the printer to check its TCP/IP settings.